# how to search data on mysql with special character?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a project and I have a listbox B on a page that has data from my db which I filtered from another listbox A, and that two listbox is my query for the reports that I needed. The problem is that one of the data on the list box contain special characters in particular a parenthesis. If I queried the report using the normal string it does have an output however if the filtered data on the listbox B has special character it doesn't show any data which should have.

I already used options such as `mysqli_real_escape_string, COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` and `mysqli_query($conn,'SET NAMES utf8');`
`mysqli_query($conn,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");` but to know prevail. can someone help me here?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ERRORDB');
 mysqli_query($conn,'SET NAMES utf8');
mysqli_query($conn,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
 $output = '';
$brgy_add = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['address']);

$sql  = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(LASTNAME,', ',FIRSTNAME,' ',MATERNALNAME) AS Fname FROM voters WHERE BARANGAYNAME COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '{brgy_add}' AND CLEADER = 'LEADER' ORDER BY CONCAT(LASTNAME,', ',FIRSTNAME,' ',MATERNALNAME) ASC";
```

Comment: $sql  = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(LASTNAME,', ',FIRSTNAME,' ',MATERNALNAME) AS Fname FROM voters WHERE BARANGAYNAME COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '\BANDOJA (LUPA-AN)' AND CLEADER = 'LEADER' ORDER BY CONCAT(LASTNAME,', ',FIRSTNAME,' ',MATERNALNAME) ASC";

Comment: IF I USED THAT QUERY I MEAN IF I QUERY IT DIRECTLY USING THAT  FORWARD SLASH THERE IS AN OUTPUT BUT IF I STORE IT IN A VARIABLE NO OUTPUT APPEARS

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, especially when it is code, preferably edit the question and don't put it in comments. It's way harder to read in the comments. Also, there's no need to SHOUT! ;)